# When I first load a Detail view from Master View it takes twice as long as each time after that

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with 60 cells. The detail view for the cells have 5 imageViews and 5 labels. When I press on a cell for the first time, it takes 2-3 seconds to load the detail view. When I go back to the MasterView and press on a cell, the same one or a different one, it is instantaneous. What could cause this massive lag and how could I fix it?

```
@implementation DetailViewController{
    NSArray *nameArray;
    NSArray *flag;
    NSArray *pop;
    NSArray *yearOfUnion;
    NSArray *area;
    NSArray *city;
    NSArray *abbreviations;
    NSArray *resNamea;
    NSArray *mainViewa;
    NSArray *plateViewa;

}
@synthesize passDataTest;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize stateint;
@synthesize cgvalue;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"%f", cgvalue);
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
     [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 920)];
} else {
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 834)];
}


[scrollView addSubview:_contentView];

[_testLabelTaco setText:passDataTest];


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"statesdata" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
flag = [dict objectForKey:@"StateFlag"];
pop = [dict objectForKey:@"Population"];
yearOfUnion = [dict objectForKey:@"Year"];
area = [dict objectForKey:@"Area"];
city = [dict objectForKey:@"LargeCity"];
abbreviations = [dict objectForKey:@"Abbreviations"];
resNamea = [dict objectForKey:@"ResNames"];
mainViewa = [dict objectForKey:@"MainViewPictures"];
plateViewa = [dict objectForKey:@"LicensePlates"];

_flagView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[flag objectAtIndex:stateint]];
_populationLabel.text = [pop objectAtIndex:stateint];
_unionYearLabel.text = [yearOfUnion objectAtIndex:stateint];
_areaLabel.text = [area objectAtIndex:stateint];
_cityLabel.text = [city objectAtIndex:stateint];
_abbrLabel.text = [abbreviations objectAtIndex:stateint];
_resNameLabel.text = [resNamea objectAtIndex:stateint];
_mainView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[mainViewa objectAtIndex:stateint]];
_plateView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[plateViewa objectAtIndex:stateint]];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

Comment: It would help to see some code

Comment: How are you loading the images in the details view? How large are the images you're loading? Its not clear that you have a leak, you might have a performance problem somewhere else.

Comment: Here's all the code in the detail view controller implementation file

Comment: OK - Your images are probably very large in size and since you're doing this in view did load the images render before the view has appeared. How large are the flag, main view and plate images that you have in your app bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting in a lot of assumption because what is relevant to your issue here is how the masterView Controller calls the detail view controller and that is not in the code you displayed.

Based on what you showed I am assuming that you are creating a new instance of your detailViewController every time you change the selection - if you are - this is what is causing your overhead.

What you need to do to make your app responsive is to separate the individual setup requirement from - (void) viewDidLoad into another method -  And in your MasterViewController call that method and bypass reinitialising the DetailVC instance again.  Note this will involve meticulous cleanup and setup but your code avoid a lot of overhead that you would otherwise incur if you keep on recreating [alloc] init]  the detail view controller instance all the time - (note - this will also keep the memory requirement down)

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%f", cgvalue);
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
       [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 920)];
     } else {
      [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 834)];
   }


     [scrollView addSubview:_contentView];

      [self setupDetailVC:self];

 }    

 -(void) setupDetailVC:(ID) sender {

    [_testLabelTaco setText:passDataTest];

     // Do any additional cleanup and setup after loading the view.  }
```

In your masterViewController: Do this

@synthesize *detailVC;   - should have been created in appDelegate code;

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       [self configureDetailItemForRow:indexPath.row];

 }

  - (void)configureDetailItemForRow:(NSUInteger)row {
   detailVC.property1 = Currentproperty;
   detailVC.Utility_sw = NO;
 //   detailVC.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
  [detailVC setupDetailVC:self];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to set the images on a separate thread, using Grand Central Dispatch. This would take the workload off the main thread and your UI shouldn't slow down. You could do something like this:

```
__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self; // to avoid a retain cycle 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread

    __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

    UIImage * flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[strongSelf->flag objectAtIndex:stateint]];
    UIImage * mainImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[strongSelf->mainViewa objectAtIndex:stateint]];
    UIImage * plateImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[strongSelf->plateViewa objectAtIndex:stateint]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates on main thread

        strongSelf->_flagView.image = flagImage;
        strongSelf->_mainView.image = mainImage;
        strongSelf->_plateView.image = plateImage;
    });
});
```